# JavaScript transform multidimensional array in one dimensional associative array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an array multidimensional that contains two nested arrays.

Looks like this:

```
$scope.multidimensionalArray = [{
            id:1,
            name:"John",
            ....
            nestedArray1:[{
                importantKey1:"important_data1",
                ....
                    nestedArray2:[{
                            importantKey2:"important_data2",
                                ....
                            }
                                 ]},
                                 ....
                                         ]}];
```

How can transform this multidimensional array in one dimensional that have to look like this:

```
$scope.oneDimensional = [
    { 
        id:1,
        name:"John",
        importantKey1:"important_data1", 
        importantKey2: "important_data2",
        ....
    },
    ....
   ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution features [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
function getProperties(o, obj) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
            getItems(o[k], obj);
        } else {
            obj[k] = o[k];
        }
    });
}        

function getItems(array, obj) {
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        getProperties(o, obj);
    });
}

var multidimensionalArray = [{ id: 1, name: "John", nestedArray1: [{ importantKey1: "important_data1", nestedArray2: [{ importantKey2: "important_data2", }] }] }, { id: 2, name: "Johanna", nestedArray1: [{ importantKey1: "important_data11", nestedArray2: [{ importantKey2: "important_data12", }] }] }],
    result = multidimensionalArray.map(function (o) {
        var obj = {};
        getProperties(o, obj);
        return obj;
    });

    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately result is the same. I  get the same multidimensional array.

Comment: Nevermind i have copied your answer wrong. It works! Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

Like in sql or generally relational databases, the only chance to have this data in ode dimension is that you multiple times use these things that are one: 
so it would be **id, name** multiple times and for each this you should have one entry from your nested array.

If there is double-level nesting, then you probably have to repeat more fields. 
Look for **JOIN** definition from sql, it may flesh something about this.